# In Java, can I inherit a class supplied by a type parameter?

Tags: java, templates, generics, inheritance, type-parameter

In java, can I do something -more or less- like this? and how?

```
public class SomeGenericClass<T> extends T{
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. What do you _really_ want to do? What's your use-case?

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question isn't all that unclear, is it? And tricky to research, I would have thought. Just because the answer is (apparently) "No, you can't do that," it doesn't mean "Can I do this?" is a bad question. (I can't quite wrap my head around why one would think one wanted to do this, but...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the fact that the question shows no personal effort to try it out and to figure it out, I'd say.

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run. Muhammad, SO is a really active place. When you ask a question, *stick around* for a few minutes so you can answer questions like the one Tunaki asked above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the relevant quote from the JLS ([§8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)):

> The ClassType [provided in the `extends` clause] must name an accessible (§6.6) class type, or a compile-time error occurs.

(The bit about accessibility isn't relevant).

A class type is [not the same thing as a type variable (§4.3)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3) (which `T` is), so attempting to do this would be a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do `public class SomeGenericClass<T> extends T` for multiple reasons:

Type erasure will erase `T` to `Object`., and it would be pointless to say `public class SomeGenericClass<T> extends Object` ,as `Object` is already the base class of all types.

Imagine if it were allowed and i did something like `public class SomeGenericClass<T extends Comparable> extends T` , type erasure will turn this into `public class SomeGenericClass<Comparable> extends Comparable` but interface is implemented not extended .

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SomeGenericClass<T> extends T{
}
```

You must understand Generics better. **SomeGenericClass** is a template (C++ terminology). As it is, it means nothing to compiler. You cannot write

```
SomeGenericClass<T> obj = new SomeGenericClass<T>() // this is invalid
```

Instead you need to supply the type attribute. This information complements the above answer provided by @Andy Turner

Comment: "this is invalid" only because of the fact that the class declaration is invalid (and the missing semicolon). Were the class definition valid, something like `<T> void foo() { SomeGenericClass<T> obj = new SomeGenericClass<T>(); }` would be valid.

Comment: I agree. But my intention was to hint the invalid usage in general. Thanks for correcting me though.